# Native charting in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2012, charts

Does Visual Studio 2012 (Ultimate) provide out of the box charting controls, especially for drawing pie, line and bar charts?

Unless I am mistaken, I have don't see any such controls in the toolbox.

Thanks

Edit:

I am using a C# solution consisting of a Winforms and ASP.NET MVC Web Api application.

Comment: The Chart control is a common choice, under the Data node in the toolbox.  Your question isn't detailed enough to judge whether you'll have it, depends on the project template you select.

Comment: Hans:  I saw the chart control under the Data node in the toolbox and assumed it was just a bar chart after adding it to the form.  There was no option to select a chart type until I clicked on the 'Series...' property, which brought up a dialog box allowing the chart type to be selected.  I guess VS2012 Ultimate does have a fully array of charting options at it's disposal.

Comment: Press F1 the next time you try this.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to figure this out so here are the steps if anyone has a similar issue:

1. Add a Chart control from the data node on the Toolbox.
2. Click on the 'Series...' property to bring up Series collection Editor dialog box.
3. Locate the ChartType property and select the type of chart required.
4. Click OK to close down the dialog.

Happy charting.

Answer (score 0):

If you open an old project (pre .NET 4) you need to change to .NET 4 for the Chart object to show up as well.